# existence of $\lambda$ in $V^*$ in an $n$ dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $U \subset V$ a subspace of dimension $n−1$.

1) Show that there exists $λ∈V^∗$ with $\ker(λ)=U$.

2) Show that if $μ ∈ V^∗$ is another linear functional with $\ker(μ) = U$, then there
exists a nonzero $c ∈ F$ such that $μ = cλ$.

I have an idea of how to prove it but I don't know how to set it up.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Pick a basis of $U$, extend it to a basis of $V$.